# Check if IP is in list of IPNetworks using netaddr

Tags: python, ip, cidr

I am having trouble doing this without multiple if statements.

pseudo code:

```
ips = [...a list of around 1000 IPs]
cidr_list = ['192.168.10.0/24', '10.10.10.0/24', '192.168.3.0/24']

for ip in ips:
    if ip in cidr_list: print ip
```

anyone know the right way to do this using IPAddress and IPNetwork from netaddr?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google `ipaddr` package for that

```
pip install ipaddr
```

from command line

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've ever used `netaddr` before, but does this work?

```
cidrs = map(IPNetwork,cidr_list)
ret = [i for i in ips if IPAddress(i) in cidrs]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you even though it is in bash and not python.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip_address_list="192.168.10.1 192.168.3.2 10.10.10.111 192.168.100.1"
cider_list="192.168.10.0/24 10.10.10.0/24 192.168.3.0/26"

bin_ip=$(IFS="." ; for i in $ip; do echo "obase=2 ; $i"| bc; done| awk '{printf "%08d", $1}'| cut -c2-)

    for cider in $cider_list ; do
        network_prefix=$(echo $cider |cut -d"/" -f2)
        network_addr=$(echo $cider |cut -d"/" -f1)
        bin_ip=$(IFS="." ; for i in $ip; do echo "obase=2 ; $i"| bc; done| awk '{printf "%08d", $1}'| cut -c2-)

        if [ $(cut -b 1-$network_prefix <<< $bin_ip) = $(cut -b 1-$network_prefix <<< $bin_network_addr) ]; then
            echo  "The IP address $ip is in $network_addr with a network prefix of $network_prefix"
        fi
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use all_matching_cidrs method from netaddr module. Simple and accurate.

`ips = [ip for ip in ips if len(netaddr.all_matching_cidrs(ip, subnet_masks))> 0]`